# How to design the tables of DB, when i have two sets of variables with same column names but different values?

Tags: arrays, multiple-columns

I want to reduce the number of tables as much as possibile. In this case it should be easy, I want to put simple informations in 2-3 tables.

I want only one row for each "entry" but i have two different arrays of values with same number of elements and same name of columns (they will correspond).

So what is the best method to design tables and put those informations inside?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the data you have and the table design you have considered?

Comment: I have a table with names of companies and their specific place; now i need one or more other tables where to put values about (for example) many instruments "contained" in that company and, for the same fields i have cells correspondent in a excel template, where i have to put the values in the end. 
It seems to me that i can't manage the situation in a good way using only one table more, except if i create an array with cells associations or other fields only for the cells in the same table (but not good programming at all).

Comment: Also i want to create less tables; the problem is that then i have to add many companies each with the specific template, but i would like to put all the data in 2-3 tables maximum, not to create 2 more tables for each different company

Comment: the 2 different sets of data i have mentioned in the question are:

1 - list of values of cells (excel)

2 - list of cell associations (excel cells, like C1, B4, D6 ecc)